# DirectX Linker error in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker, directx

I have some DirectX sample applications to work with for a University project, however I am having some issues with DirectX.

(I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and I'm on Windows Vista 64-bit) I installed the June 2010 version of the DirectX SDK (DXSDK_Jun10) however I receive an error at the end of the installation process - 'Error Code: S1023' - though checking the folders (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include etc.) the files all look like they are there.)

I opened the solution to the example project (which has worked before on other PCs using the same OS and version of Visual Studio 2008, on multiple occasions) and completed the following steps -

- Ensured Visual Studio knows where to look for linked files - Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC Directories and added the directory to the Include files and Library files (directories mentioned above)
- I right-clicked on the project solution, Properties -> Linker -> Input (for All Configurations) and linked to d3d10.lib d3dx10d.lib dxguid.lib and dxerr.lib

The compiler gives the following error "LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3d10.lib,'"

I have checked and d3d10.lib is in Lib\x64 and Lib\x86 both.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I have tried adding the library to 'Additional Dependencies' as a poster suggested below. I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the library directory in the linker options:
Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories